# Buscar dado de um data frame a partir dos dados em outro

Tags: r

Estou com uma demanda que não consigo resolver. O problema é o seguinte: eu tenho duas tabelas e preciso pesquisar se há pessoas iguais nas duas tabelas, caso sim preciso ver o quanto ela ganha na segunda tabela e transportar para a primeira (numa nova coluna), porém ele acaba pegando os valores de forma 'aleatória', abaixo está o código que eu fiz:

```
pensionista.especial <- read.xlsx("PensaoEspecial.xlsx")
pensionista.janeiro <- read.xlsx("PensaoMensal12.xlsx")

pensionista.janeiro <- transform(pensionista.janeiro, PensaoEsp = ifelse(ID.FUNCIONAL %in% pensionista.especial$ID.FUNCIONAL,
                                                                         1 ,0))

pensionista.janeiro <- transform(pensionista.janeiro, InstEsp = ifelse(ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR %in% pensionista.especial$ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR,
                                                                       1, 0))

basedetrabalho <- pensionista.janeiro[ , c(1,10,13,14,23,31,32,33,34,69, 78, 79)]

basedetrabalho <- transform(basedetrabalho, VB_ESP = ifelse(ID.FUNCIONAL %in% pensionista.especial$ID.FUNCIONAL, pensionista.especial$VL_BRUTO, 0))
```

Peço ajuda com esse problema pessoal!

Answer (score 1):

Já consegui a solução, foi através da função merge

```
merge(pensionista.janeiro, pensionista.especial[,c("ID.FUNCIONAL","VL_BRUTO")],
  by.x = "ID.FUNCIONAL", by.y = "ID.FUNCIONAL", all.x = TRUE)
```